# Using expressions in generic QGIS Print Layout inserted tables

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I would like to use expressions in tables added in QGIS Print Layout using the **Add Fixed Table** option, as shown in the screenshot attached the expressions are instead displayed as regular text in the table's cells

[image: Screenshot showing expression in value in Label above and regular text in table]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality is coming in QGIS 3.16. It's already available in the nightly releases for testing.